# В csv файл записывается только последняя страница сайта, помогите пожалуйста

Tags: python, парсер, csv

```
from _csv import reader
import requests
import row as row
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/list_basic/?page=1'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
items = soup.find_all('div', class_='col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4')

for n, i in enumerate(items, start=1):
    itemName = i.find('h4', class_='card-title').text.strip()
    itemPrice = i.find('h5').text
    print(f'{n}: {itemName} за {itemPrice}')

pages = soup.find('ul', class_='pagination')
urls = []
links = pages.find_all('a', class_='page-link')

for link in links:
    pageNum = int(link.text) if link.text.isdigit() else None
    if pageNum != None:
        hrefval = link.get('href')
        urls.append(hrefval)

for slug in urls:
    newUrl = url.replace('?page=1', slug)
    response = requests.get(newUrl)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4')

    for n, i in enumerate(items, start=n):
        itemName = i.find('h4', class_='card-title').text.strip()
        itemPrice = i.find('h5').text
        print(f'{n}: {itemName} за {itemPrice}')

with open('data.csv','w',newline='') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerow(['NAME ------ PRICE'])
    entries = soup.find_all('div', class_='col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4')
    for entry in entries:
        itemName = entry.find('h4', class_='card-title').text.strip()
        itemPrice = entry.find('h5').text
        w.writerow([f'{itemName} ------ {itemPrice}'])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerow([f'''NAME {'-'*28} PRICE'''])
 
    page = 1
    while True:
        url = f'https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/list_basic/?page={page}'
        response = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
        if page == 1:
            pages = soup.find('ul', class_='pagination')
            page_max = max([int(x.text) for x in pages.find_all('a', class_='page-link') if x.text.isdigit()])

        entries = soup.find_all('div', class_='col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4')
        for entry in entries:
            itemName = entry.find('h4', class_='card-title').text.strip()
            itemPrice = entry.find('h5').text
            print(f'''{itemName} {'-'*(32-len(itemName))} {itemPrice}''')
            w.writerow([f'''{itemName} {'-'*(32-len(itemName))} {itemPrice}'''])

        if page == page_max:
            break
        page += 1
```

ответ

```
Short Dress --------------------- $24.99
Patterned Slacks ---------------- $29.99
Short Chiffon Dress ------------- $49.99
...
...
T-shirt ------------------------- $6.99
T-shirt ------------------------- $6.99
Blazer -------------------------- $49.99
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте изменить алгоритм поиска количества страниц, примерно на такой:

```
try:
        page = last_page = 1
        while page <= last_page:
            url = url_search

            if page > 0:
                url = f'{url_search}page={page}/?Search=Gazer'

            print(f'Load: {url}')
            response.get(url)

            for item_el in *Ваш контейнер с информацией о товаре*:
                *Тут забираете инфу о товаре (имя, цена и тд)*

            try:
                last_page = *забираете последний элемент пагинации, в вашем случае это номер 7*

            except NoSuchElementException:
                break

            page += 1
```